# Open chrome path having space in it from Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-config, filepath

I'm trying to add config in my `webpack.dev.js` file such that it opens Chrome in Disabled web security mode. When i put the value as "chrome" in `open`, It opens regular chrome correctly. But unable to open chrome with disabled security mode. It gives the below error.

```
const devConfig = merge(common, {
    plugins,
    watchOptions: {
        ...
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: [ROOT],
        disableHostCheck: true,
        useLocalIp: false,
        host: '127.0.0.4',
        port: 9080,
        overlay: {
            errors: true
        },
        open: "chrome --user-data-dir='C:/Chrome dev session' --disable-web-security --allow-file-access-from-file",
        historyApiFallback: true,
        watchContentBase: true
    }
});
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: If your goal is to have 2 services running under the same domain name once in production, maybe disabling web security when running it locally is not the cleanest solution. Using [WebPack Dev Server's proxy option](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy) to simulate that locally might make more sense

Comment: Ok @blex. Let me try that.